Direct register manipulation on Arduino Uno R4
I want to generate a PWM signal on pin 9 (P303) using direct register manipulation. The new chip used on the Arduino Uno R4 is from Renesas and I found the documentation for the it. The problem is that I think that the Arduino IDE does not have support for this microcontroller registers like they do for the Atmega328 chips. For example, I tried to call the register GPT321.GTPR but the IDE does not recognize it. How should I solve this problem?



You are going to need some kind of header file that declares/supports this register. If you want your IDE/compiler to "know" the GPT321 register, it's going to need information that this exists.

A suitable device header (and tools to use the Arduino hardware without the somewhat simplistic Arduino framework) is included with https://www.renesas.com/us/en/software-tool/flexible-software-package-fsp.  Details of the register level access at https://renesas.github.io/fsp/_i_o_d_e_f_i_n_e__o_v_e_r_v_i_e_w.html.  Note that the names and macros you have invented do not match those defined by the vendor.  R_GPT321->GPTR = 255 I think is correct if you use the vendor's header.  Since this is a "where can I find the library" type question and off-topic, posting as a comment only.

There's a guy over at the Arduino forum that found a header file for this kind of hardware:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/the-renesas-users-manual-and-fsp-the-deep-magic-for-r4/1179100/1
For him, the location was:

/home/david/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/renesas_uno/1.0.4/variants/MINIMA/includes/ra/fsp/src/bsp/cmsis/Device/RENESAS/Include/R7FA4M1AB.h


Hey that's me!  Upvote
